# Paypal rest with https

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I changed my site to HTTPS but my PayPal now does not work.
It takes me to a page that with an invalid request error and a return to merchant button.

Is there something I need to change, using paypal rest 
Thanks

Comment: There must be an 8 ball somewhere that will answer your question [the way it's written](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You may file a ticket to the PayPal MTS guys here:
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/

With detailed errors and maybe access logs, you will get an solution there